# Swift: How to convert Date() to timezone of Apple's server to validate receipt?

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, in-app-purchase, storekit

Using Swift 3

When I call this code it shows as my timezone

```
let date = Date()
let todayDate = formatter.string(from: date)
print(todayDate)
```

I called the JSON response from the StoreKit receipt to check the `original_purchase_date` and `expires_date` to compare it to `todayDate` to validate the receipt.

What I want to do, for example

```
if (todayDate > expires_date ) {
    cancel subscription
}
```

I can't match the dates if Apple's purchase_date and expires_date are in GMT timezone while todayDate is in whatever timezone the user is in.

So I just need to convert whatever timezone the user is in when Date() is called and convert it to GMT like Apple's server so I can check if todayDate has passed the expired data on the Auto renewable subscription.

Also, is this a good approach to prevent from in app hacks? I got the receipt from my server using php which validates it from Apple.

```
if parseJSON["status"] as? Int == 0 {

print("Status Code for Receipt = 0!")

// Checking "latest_receipt_info"
if let receiptInfo: NSArray = parseJSON["latest_receipt_info"] as? NSArray {
    let lastReceipt = receiptInfo.lastObject as! NSDictionary

    // Get last receipt
    print("\nLAST RECEIPT INFORMATION: \n", lastReceipt)

    // Format date
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale!

    // Get "original_purchase_date" as NSDate
    let subscriptionBoughtDate: NSDate = formatter.date(from: lastReceipt["original_purchase_date"] as! String) as NSDate!
    print("\n   - DATE BOUGHT SUBSCRIPTION = \(subscriptionBoughtDate)\n")

    // Get "expires_date" as NSDate
    let subscriptionExpirationDate: NSDate = formatter.date(from: lastReceipt["expires_date"] as! String) as NSDate!
    print("\n   - DATE SUBSCRIPTION EXPIRES = \(subscriptionExpirationDate)\n")

    // Get Todays Date
    let date = Date()
    let todayDate = formatter.string(from: date)
    print("\n   - DATE TODAY = \(todayDate)\n")

    // See if current date has passed expired date
}
```

JSON response

```
LAST RECEIPT INFORMATION: 
{
"expires_date" = "2017-08-03 04:50:08 Etc/GMT";
"expires_date_ms" = 1501735808000;
"expires_date_pst" = "2017-08-02 21:50:08 America/Los_Angeles";
"is_trial_period" = false;
"original_purchase_date" = "2017-08-02 15:27:27 Etc/GMT";
"original_purchase_date_ms" = 1501687647000;
"original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-08-02 08:27:27 America/Los_Angeles";
"original_transaction_id" = 1000000552288255;
"product_id" = "com.example.gg.month";
"purchase_date" = "2017-08-03 04:45:08 Etc/GMT";
"purchase_date_ms" = 1501735508000;
"purchase_date_pst" = "2017-08-02 21:45:08 America/Los_Angeles";
quantity = 1;
"transaction_id" = 1000000568853433;
"web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000055887122;
}

- DATE BOUGHT SUBSCRIPTION = 2017-08-02 15:27:27 +0000


- DATE SUBSCRIPTION EXPIRES = 2017-08-03 04:50:08 +0000


- DATE TODAY = 2017-08-04 17:26:51 America/New_York
```

Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need `original_purchase_date` at all? Isn't `todayDate > expires_date` enough?

Comment: honestly it’s just added security, the purchased date may be modified so the trial last longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to set up the `TimeZone` property of your `DateFormatter` to GMT.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

A general advice: don't use `Foundation` types in `Swift` when native `Swift` alternatives are available, such as `Array`, `Dictionary`, `Locale` and `Date`. Use these instead of `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSLocale` and `NSDate`.

Comment: Wow!! This is the perfect answer! All answers plays around with different Date Formats but this is perfect for Subscription expires date in the received receipt for validation.

Answer (score 4):

I would not mess with date formatters at all. There are various dates in the JSON with the suffix "_ms". Those are dates based on the Unix "epoch date", but multiplied by 1000.

If all you need to do is to see if the current date falls between the subscription start date and the end date, you can compare those date values ending in "_ms" directly, as integer values.

If you need to convert one of those dates to a Date object, that's easy.

Here's an example:

```
let expiresDateValue = Double(lastReceipt["expires_date_ms"]) / 1000
let expiresDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: expiresDateValue)
```

### Edit:

Swift's strict type-casting makes this more of a pain than it should be.

Do this:

```
var expiresSeconds: Double = 0
if let expiresString = lastReceipt["expires_date_ms"] as? String,
  let expiresMS = Double(expiresString) {
  expiresSeconds = expiresMS / 1000
}
```

Comment: Is there any benefits from using ms instead of date formatters?

Comment: It's easier, simpler, and cleaner.

Comment: I tried it and its giving me an error on the first line saying `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(Any?)'`

Comment: Now the error is saying `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String'`

Comment: I tried `Double` instead of `String` but it prints the wrong response `ms: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000`

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I should know better than to type out code in the editor without testing it.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Quick question, would this be enough security for an auto-renewable subscription. Just seeing if todays date passed the expired date? Anything else I should do to prevent hacks?

Comment: I haven't looked at StoreKit in any detail in a couple of years. I can't remember how receipt validation works. Off the top of my head, though, checking dates does not sound like it provides much security. Is it your job to check that the receipt is properly signed, or does Apple do that? (On Mac OS the developer has to validate that the app is properly signed.)

Comment: I validate the receipt through my server and when I get it apple provides status codes to tell you if its authenticated. So I'm guessing its working but I should make a post to ask.